# SSMS error 0x80070643

Tags: ssms

I am trying to install SSMS 2017 and i got the following error.

```
[307C:1F00][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2017
[307C:1F00][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i319: Applied rollback package: SQLSysClrTypes.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[36B0:0CDC][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {9D78F5D4-79D2-4FC6-AC56-F364A0ABC54F}, package: SQLSysClrTypes.msi
[36B0:0CDC][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i351: Removing cached package: SQLSysClrTypes.msi, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9D78F5D4-79D2-4FC6-AC56-F364A0ABC54F}v14.0.1000.169\
[307C:1F00][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 100
[36B0:0CDC][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {a4f19bdb-56d9-4fe3-8139-f4b0ffe2b9f7}
[36B0:0CDC][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i352: Removing cached bundle: {a4f19bdb-56d9-4fe3-8139-f4b0ffe2b9f7}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a4f19bdb-56d9-4fe3-8139-f4b0ffe2b9f7}\
[307C:1F00][2018-05-19T18:52:38]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Error irrecuperable durante la instalación (0x80070643)
[307C:1F00][2018-05-19T18:52:38]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[307C:2530][2018-05-19T18:53:04]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\cgome\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20180519185023.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. sql server odbc driver 17 deleted
2. Restart the computer
3. And reload ssms

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues which could be causing this:

1. Insufficient Permissions
2. Windows Update issues
3. .NET framework issues

Aside from a full computer "refresh". I have come across a fix for this on another post which I hope will help...

Fix worked for another:

Remove every trace of .Net and C++ (Programs and Features) including Microsoft .Net and Microsoft Visual Studio C++.

Delete, Restart, Install and Re-install Visual Studio etc

Resolution foud here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/17786747-5f50-4968-9e06-81c25a5af93d/unable-to-install-sql-server-management-studio-2017-fatal-error-0x80070643?forum=sqltools

Comment: and also buy a new computer... what else?

Answer (score 1):

I  was getting the following error :

---

[image]

I solved it by doing the following :

- Download the **sqlncli.dll** from here  https://www.azdll.net/files/search?q=sqlncli
- Place it in your **C:\Windows\System32** folder
- Install an older copy of SMSS, I used version 17.9.1 instead. The current version at this time is 18.6

If that does not work for some reason, try uninstalling your Visual C++ Redistributable along with Visual Studio if you have it installed, restart you comp and run through through the process above detailed again.

Comment: no dll is being found at the shared link

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with **SSMS 18.7** on *Windows 10* and followed these steps to resolve the problem:

1. Downloading the [sqlncli.dll](https://www.azdll.net/files/search?q=sqlncli)
2. Copying `sqlncli.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32` directory. These two steps are the same as Fabii's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438662/3955129).
3. Re-run **SSMS 18.7** installer.

Then my problem was resolved. I didn't uninstall anything else nor did any other change.

Comment: no dll is being found at the shared link